# 'CommonApplicationData' folder path of another computer

Tags: c#

the client has an app installed on his system whereas the main system containing the client's database  is in separate network and has an file which is sent to the client's system. this file is read by the app and displays it to the user in required manner. If the client wants to make any changes, it is made through the app to the file and is sent back to the server's CommonApplicationData folder. If the connection can't be established, the program automatically tries to upload client's data after a defined interval.

the problem is that how can i send a file to the server's specific folder because Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData gives the path of client's system and not server's. And in order to retry uploading file onto server , do I need a Windows service or something else?
if the server address is ,suppose'192.168.10.3' then how client can save a file in server's CommonApplicationData folder?

Comment: Can you get the server to tell you the path to save it at?

Comment: For security the application uses the common application data folder of the system. The application then uses the file from this location without the user's knowledge of the file location and file's information.

Comment: If you mention security, I would certainly not give _any_ client direct acces to the server's file system. Why not create very simple upload service where the client sends the fiel to, and the service stores it wherever it wants. It's none of the client's business to know where a server stores its files.

Comment: I am not providing client any access to the server. It is the windows service running on the client system that uploads the file to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server component could have a WCF call exposed via IIS which could receive the file from your client app call and then write it to the appropriate location.